# how to check connection is build properly in codeigniter after configure database.php file?

Tags: codeigniter

this is my controller code for setting hostname,username,password,database_name programmatically & it's work properly in my code

```
  function submit_installation()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->database();

    if($_POST)
    {
        //--------------------to config database file----------------------
        $old_hostname = '$db[\'default\'][\'hostname\']';
        $old_username = '$db[\'default\'][\'username\']';
        $old_password = '$db[\'default\'][\'password\']';
       $old_database = '$db[\'default\'][\'database\']';
        $fileName = "./application/config/database.php";


        $file = file($fileName);

        foreach( $file as $key=>$line ) {
            if( false !== strpos($line, $old_hostname) )
            {
                $file[$key]=$old_hostname."='".$_POST['hostname']."';\n";
            }
            elseif( false !== strpos($line, $old_username) )
            {
                $file[$key]=$old_username."='".$_POST['username']."';\n";
            }
            elseif( false !== strpos($line, $old_password) )
               {
                  $file[$key]=$old_password."='".$_POST['password']."';\n";
              }
            elseif( false !== strpos($line, $old_database) )
            {
                $file[$key]=$old_database."='".$_POST['database']."';\n";
            }
        }


        file_put_contents($fileName, $file);
}
}
```

in database.php following code show database setting after execute controller file & changes made in database.php file.

```
    <?php

$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE
 $db['default']['hostname']='xxx';
 $db['default']['username']='abc';
 $db['default']['password']='abc';
 $db['default']['database']='xyz';
    $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

so how to check database connection is made or not using back-end code?

Answer (score 1):

I think You have to try this one:

```
$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'abc';
$db_pass        = 'xyz';
$db_database    = 'qwerty'; 
$link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish a DB connection');
```

This one is easy method.